# How do I prevent a "Page not found" error for URLs containing non-Latin characters?

Tags: 7, uri

I have a site that uses non-latin characters in URLs, e.g. [http://example.com/drupal/новости](http://example.com/drupal/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). When the URL is copy-pasted, some browsers change the URL to http://example.com/drupal/%ED%EE%E2%EE%F1%F2%E8, and this causes an *Page not found* error.

How do I make Drupal understand both [http://example.com/drupal/новости](http://example.com/drupal/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) and http://example.com/drupal/%ED%EE%E2%EE%F1%F2%E8?

Answer (score 3):

Consider trying the [Transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> ... it takes Unicode text and tries to represent it in US-ASCII characters (universally displayable, unaccented characters) by attempting to transliterate the pronunciation expressed by the text in some other writing system to Roman letters.

As a sample, it transforms an URL like `mydomain.com/последние-новости-в-Украине-и-мире` in something like `mydoamin/poslednie-novosti-v-Ukraine-i-mire`.

Other modules that might help to solve this question:

- [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect).
- [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto).

Comment: I don't want to change the existing URLs.

Comment: Would it be acceptable in your case to have one of both URLs be like an "alias" of the other "URL"? Similar to redirecting an "old" path of some node automatically to the "new" path of that same node?